# MongoDB Java - Translate query to mongodb Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a wierd problem. I have a query which I am sure it works, but when I translated it in Java it does not return anything.

The MongoDB query is:

```
db.births.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "day" : "March_13",
            "events.year": "1929",
            "events.info": /American/
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$events" },
    {
        "$match": {
            "day" : "March_13",
            "events.year": "1929",
            "events.info": /American/
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "day": { "$first": "$day" },
            "events": { "$push": "$events" }
        }
    }

])
```

The Java code is:

```
AggregateIterable<Document> result = mongoDatabase.getCollection(category).
    aggregate(
            Arrays.asList(
                    new Document("$match",
                            new Document("day", day).
                                    append("events.year", year).
                                    append("events.info", "/" + word + "/")),
                    new Document("$unwind", "$events"),
                    new Document("$match",
                            new Document("day", day).
                                    append("events.year", year).
                                    append("events.info", "/" + word + "/")),
                    new Document("$group",
                            new Document("_id", "$_id").
                                    append("day", new Document("$first", "$day")).
                                    append("events", new Document("$push", "$events")))));
```

Please have a look and tell me if the way I translated it into Java is wrong or there is something else.

Thank you!

Comment: "category" Java variable is pointing to "births" MongoDB collection?

Comment: @zeugor category can point to births/deaths/events/holidays, in what I am testing I always enter births there.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the MongoDB syntax, but aren't you creating something like "/American/" (string type) instead of /American/ - without double quotes? What type is /American/ in MongoDB query? Is there an equivalent on Java for that? Again, sorry if that makes no sense, I've got no experience in MongoDB, just a suggestion/question.

Comment: @MichałSchielmann I think you are right! In the actual query there are no quotes, and thus is not a string. Thanks mate, I will check right now.

Comment: @PetruDanielTudosiu What is /American/ in your MongoDB query? Is it an regex?

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can try this:

```
String m = "American";
DBObject eventInfoObject = new BasicDBObject(
  "events.info", 
  java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(m)
);
```

This send to the MongoDB server the query `{ "events.info" : { "$regex" : "American"}}`

In your code replace:

```
"/" + word + "/"
```

with:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(word)
```